# Правильная отправка json строки серверу и через какой поток ввода должен принять строку серверjava

Tags: java, json, клиент-сервер

Клиент отправляет серверу JSON строку объекта `Message` у которой 2 поля: `String data`, `Date currentDate`. Отправка происходит через `PrintWriter` (метод `println()`).

Не знаю как принять серверу эту строку т.к. `BufferedReader` не подходит (т.к. JSON строка состоит из нескольких строк, а `bufferedReader.readLine()` считывает только одну строку.

Пробовал убрать из строки все переносы строки, но сервер все равно не может восстановить нормально объект `Message` (этот класс скопирован из клиента слово в слово).

**Как правильно должен отправить клиент JSON и через что должен принять эту строку сервер?**

Скорее всего сервер должен прочитать всю переданную строку, но я не знаю (через `InputStreamReader` не получается (мб не верно делаю).
Заранее спасибо.

Кстати возможно проблема даже не в этом, если я образую все новые строки и все отсылает в одной строчке, объект `Message` все равно не правильно создается, хотя я класс скопировал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К вопросу

> и через что должен принять эту строку сервер?

С помощью BufferedReader можно считать все имеющиеся данные, не только одну строку.

```
InputStream inputStream = ..//создаете inputStream из источника данных
try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {

        StringBuilder rawJson = new StringBuilder();
        String readLine;
        while ((readLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(readLine); //для понимания, что происходит, выводим в консоль считанные данные
            rawJson.append(readLine);
        }
        String jsonString = rawJson.toString();
    }
```

После считывания полной строки, преобразуете ее в json.

Comment: спасибо большое, это как раз часто нужно. Теперь буду знать как правильно это делать

Answer (score 1):

Ну вобщем я сделал ошибку за которую мне будет стыдно всю жизнь: забыл создать объект Gson (т.е. написать `Gson gson = new Gson();`. Так что все работает если убрать из json строчки все переходы на новую строку. Вопрос закрыт